# Ini files: DeleteKey leaves empty section

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, ini

When an ini file contains a section with only one key (like `MySection1` in

```
[MySection1]
MyKey1=MyValue1
[MySection2]
...
```

) calling `DeleteKey` for that key leaves an empty section:

```
[MySection1]
[MySection2]
...
```

I'd prefer if that empty section would be removed too. Of course I can call something like

```
if not ini.SectionExists('MySection1') then
  ini.EraseSection('MySection1');
```

after every call to `DeleteKey` (or make an overridden `TExtIniFile.DeleteKey` do that) but I hope there is an automatic way to make Windows or the VCL do that. Do you know any?

**Update:** I'm using a TIniFile descendant that solely adds some additional Read*/Write* methods.

**Update:** My test routine:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ini: TMyIniFile;
begin
  ini := TMyIniFile.Create(cIniFileName);
  try
    ini.WriteString('MySection1', 'MyKey1', 'MyValue1');
    ini.DeleteKey('MySection1', 'MyKey1');
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;

  Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Show;
begin
  if FileExists(cIniFileName) then
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(cIniFileName)
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
end;
```

`TMyIniFile` can be an alias for `TIniFile` or a descendant of `TMemIniFile` with an  destructor calling `UpdateFile`.

Comment: Are you using `TIniFile` or `TMemIniFile`?

Comment: Just to clarify, `SectionExists` returns `false` if the section 'exists' but has no (that is, 0) keys in it?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes. The name is suboptimal. :-)

Comment: Does it behave more nicely with `TMemIniFile`?

Comment: @David: No. TMemIniFile adds empty lines between sections (which looks nice) but still leaves empty sections.

Comment: @Ulrich Reading the code to `TMemIniFile` I find that surprising.

Comment: @David: I updated my post with my test routines. I don't see much room for making an error there. :-)

Comment: @Andreas No [from doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.SectionExists):"SectionExists returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the section in question exists". What Ulrich want is `ini.ReadSection('MySection1', sl); if(sl.count = 0)then ini.EraseSection('MySection1');`

Comment: @ain: The core of `TCustomIniFile.SectionExists` reads `ReadSection(Section, S); Result := S.Count > 0;` - so my snippet from above is eqivalent to yours, isn't it?

Comment: @Ulrich Looks like youre right! I consider it to be a bug in TCustomIniFile as it returns wrong result for a empty section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is "automatic way to make Windows or the VCL do that". I believe that the reason is that "API" doesn't know that you don't intend to use that section anymore (ie if the API would delete the section after you delete the last key someone would complain that this is inefficient as they intend to add an key to that section later and so the section must be recreated). Also, one could argue that the existence of the empty section carries information too and thus that information would be lost in case of automatic deletion.

Comment: I guess you're right - I found postings specifically asking how to add empty sections.

Comment: Since the parsed ini file content is the same with or without the empty section, I have to disagree with your statement that the empty section does carry information.

Comment: As you use custon descendatn already just add an `DeleteKeyAndSectionIfEmpty()` method to your class.

Comment: @Smasher But you can test for the existence of the section - `SectionExists()` method in case on TIniFile - which is 1 bit on information.

Comment: Accepted - I think I'll go with the mainstream and live with the ugliness of having empty sections. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that either `TIniFile` or `TMemIniFile` will operate the way you want. Therefore the possible solutions are:

1. Override `DeleteKey` as you suggest.
2. Override `UpdateFile` and remove all *empty* sections at that point.